# Why button animations don't fire in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

After adding GameObject to Hierarchy, I added Image and Button components.

I then set the button's transition settings to animation.

I created a button controller and added sprite images to Normal, Pressed, Highlighted, and Disabled, respectively, to create an animation.

Normal animation works well, but Pressed, Highlited animation does not.

Why is this a problem?

Due to this problem, we are unable to proceed to the next step. Please help me.

I wrote the question with the same problem

The link is below.

[Why does not the button animatIon in Unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753677/why-does-not-the-button-animation-in-unity)

Please help me. I need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Image and Button components that are part of the Unity UI (`Component -> UI -> Image`) then these components require a *Canvas* in order to render.

Instead of creating an empty game object and adding these components manually, use the `GameObject -> UI -> Button` menu option.  Unity will automatically add the new GameObject to an existing canvas, or create one.